# Rewriting VertexPositionTexture to use integer Vectors

Tags: c#, xna-4.0

I'm currently working on a project that involves setting an enormous amount of vertex data using VertexPositionTextures. This ends up eating up a lot of memory, and while there's some optimization I can do as far as what is currently in memory and what can be offloaded to the hard-drive, I would like to optimize in every way possible.

My question then: is there a way I can rewrite the VertexPositionTexture struct such that it uses my custom IntVector classes to use less space? Would this require modifications to DrawPrimitives and DrawUserPrimitives as well?

I ask this because I'm not using a texture atlas, so my UV coordinates are always (0,0),(0,1),(1,0),(1,1) which can be represented without floats, and my vertex positions can be easily represented by integers as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes, you can do this.** You just have to define a custom vertex format and XNA will do the rest.

The most important thing to keep in mind is that you are limited to using elements in the available `VertexElementFormat`s ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.vertexelementformat.aspx)) - noting that the `HalfVector` formats are not available in the `Reach` profile ([info](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2010/03/12/reach-vs-hidef.aspx)).

**You probably don't need to create your own vector types**, because XNA already provides implementations for all usable formats in `Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.PackedVector` ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.packedvector)) or in the main library. If you do want to create your own type, it needs to be a `struct` (or loose fields in your vertex) that packs in the same way.

Finally, it's worth pointing out that there is no 32-bit `int` data type. And there would be no benefit, either, because a `float` (a `Single`) is the same size at 32 bits. (And some GPUs operate in single-precision, so you wouldn't get to keep the extra precision anyway.)

---

So we're starting with a `VertexPositionTexture` containing a `Vector3` position (96 bits) and a `Vector2` texture coordinate (64 bits) for a total of 160 bits.

Let's turn that into a custom `IntVertexPositionTexture` that contains a `Short4` position (64 bits) and a `NormalizedShort2` texture coordinate (32 bits) for a total of 96 bits (40% size reduction).

(If you're working in 2D, you could use `Short2` instead of `Short4` and save another 32 bits. There is no `Short3`.)

Here's the code for this vertex type, which is really just a case of knowing what the API expects:

```
struct IntVertexPositionTexture : IVertexType
{
    public Short4 Position;
    public NormalizedShort2 TextureCoordinate;

    public IntVertexPositionTexture(Short4 position, NormalizedShort2 textureCoordinate)
    {
        this.Position = position;
        this.TextureCoordinate = textureCoordinate;
    }

    public static readonly VertexDeclaration VertexDeclaration = new VertexDeclaration(new VertexElement[]
    {
        new VertexElement(0, VertexElementFormat.Short4, VertexElementUsage.Position, 0),
        new VertexElement(8, VertexElementFormat.NormalizedShort2, VertexElementUsage.TextureCoordinate, 0),
    });

    VertexDeclaration IVertexType.VertexDeclaration
    {
        get { return IntVertexPositionTexture.VertexDeclaration; }
    }
}
```

The important thing when creating a custom vertex type is to make sure the fields match the order and layout that you specify in the `VertexDeclaration` ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.vertexdeclaration.aspx)). How you create your `VertexDeclaration` should be self-explanatory - just have a look at the [MSDN page for `VertexElement`'s constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff433870(v=xnagamestudio.40)). The offset of each field is specified in bytes.

The `elementUsage` and `usageIndex` match up to [vertex shader semantics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb509647(v=vs.85).aspx#VS) in HLSL. So in this custom format we have `POSITION0` and `TEXCOORD0`.

The use of `IVertexType` is optional, as you can also pass a `VertexDeclaration` directly to (for example) a `VertexBuffer` constructor instead.

---

That should be all the info you need if you want to make a different vertex format to the one I've provided. For more info, there is a [blog post by Shawn Hargreaves](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2010/04/19/vertex-data-in-xna-game-studio-4-0.aspx) that goes into more detail about the API.

Comment: Thank you Andrew, this is a very useful response! :)

Comment: This is so useful answer, I've been searching for it for quite a bit of time. Thank you!